# Get a specific word and the following one in a string

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I would like to get the Genus and species name in a string. 
Example :

`"He saw a Panthera leo in the savanna"`

I wish to get `"Panthera leo"` with specify the genus name.

I tried to use the `word` function (package `stringr`) :

```
my_sentence<-"He saw a Panthera leo in the savanna"
word(my_sentence,"Panthera",+1)
```

I know the problem is from the "+1" argument. Do you have any clue ?

Maybe I should use the gsub function ?

Comment: Just `ind <- grep('Panthera', strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]);
word(x, ind, ind+1)
[1] "Panthera leo"`

Answer (score 1):

```
my_sentence<-"He saw a Panthera leo in the savanna"
x = strsplit(my_sentence, " ")
index = grep("Panthera", x, value=F)
want =x[c(index, index+1)][[1]]
```

Comment: couple of things. The default value for `grep` is already `FALSE` (no need to specify it). Also when there are more sentences, `unlist(strsplit(...))` will give wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Regex-Fu:

```
> m <- gregexpr('panthera\\W\\w\\w+', "He saw a Panthera leo in the 
savanna", ignore.case = T)
> regmatches("He saw a Panthera leo in the savanna", m)
[[1]]
[1] "Panthera leo"
```

The `\W\w\w+` is one non-word character, one word character, and then one or more word characters. That means that whatever comes after panthera has to have at least 2 characters.

In `stringr` it looks like this:

```
> s <- "He saw a Panthera leo in the savanna"
> pat <- regex('panthera\\W\\w\\w+', ignore_case = T)
> str_extract(s, pat)
[1] "Panthera leo"
```

I think I prefer that.